# Getting parse error while placing the string in the query

Tags: php, mysql, php-parse-error

Here is my php code.Browser is generating a warning when i am trying to execute the code.

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php");


$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected successfully'; 

mysql_select_db('lookup') or die('Could not select database');

$query = 'SELECT airport_id FROM airport';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

echo "<table>\n"; 

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
 echo "\t<tr>\n";
 foreach ($line as $col_value) 
 {
   echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
   $query1= 'SELECT distinct c.airport_ident,c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type
      FROM corept.std_star_leg
      WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='$col_value'
      GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
      ON c.sequence_num=b.seq AND c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
      WHERE  c.data_supplier='J'  AND c.airport_ident='$col_value'  AND

      NOT EXISTS

     (SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d
      WHERE d.apt=$col_value AND d.name!=d.trans
      AND c.star_ident=d.name and c.fix_ident=d.trans)

      UNION

     SELECT apt,name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d WHERE apt='$col_value' AND name!=trans
     AND

     NOT EXISTS

    (SELECT distinct c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type FROM corept.std_star_leg
      WHERE data_supplier='J'  AND  airport_ident='$col_value'
      GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
      ON c.sequence_num=b.seq  AND  c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
      WHERE c.data_supplier='J' AND  c.airport_ident=$col_value AND d.name=c.star_ident  AND d.trans=c.fix_ident)';

   $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
  while ($line1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
  {
   echo "\t<tr>\n";
   foreach ($line as $col_value) 
    {
     echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
     echo "\t</tr>\n";
    }
  }
 echo "\t</tr>\n";
}}
echo "</table>\n";

 mysql_free_result($result);

 mysql_close($link);
?>
```

When i am trying to execute the above code it is generating a warning at line 22 where i included $col_value into my query.Please help me to rectify it.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the concatenation (`.`) operator:

```
$str = "Part 1" . $value . "Part 2";
```

However, please don't query like this, use **[parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)** instead. Such code leads to **[SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** attacks and/or minor performance degradation.

Comment: +1 for mentioning sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

use this query. The problem was that you started your string with `'` and used `'` around variables but forgot to escape them.

```
$query1= "SELECT distinct c.airport_ident,c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type
  FROM corept.std_star_leg
  WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='$col_value'
  GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
  ON c.sequence_num=b.seq AND c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
  WHERE  c.data_supplier='J'  AND c.airport_ident='$col_value'  AND

  NOT EXISTS

 (SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d
  WHERE d.apt=$col_value AND d.name!=d.trans
  AND c.star_ident=d.name and c.fix_ident=d.trans)

  UNION

 SELECT apt,name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d WHERE apt='$col_value' AND name!=trans
 AND

 NOT EXISTS

(SELECT distinct c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type FROM corept.std_star_leg
  WHERE data_supplier='J'  AND  airport_ident='$col_value'
  GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
  ON c.sequence_num=b.seq  AND  c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
  WHERE c.data_supplier='J' AND  c.airport_ident=$col_value AND d.name=c.star_ident  AND d.trans=c.fix_ident)";
```

Comment: Thank you..it worked..but the query is getting replaced as OOC what i need is to be replaced as 'OOC'.How can i do that?

Comment: put `$col_value` inside `''`, it will be `'$col_value'` then it will be replaced as `'OOC'`

Comment: thats what u did there...its already in quotes

Comment: @user2037445 but in some place its not. like here `c.airport_ident=$col_value`

Comment: I replaced it..but its not working.. :(

Comment: Can you tell what is not working?

Comment: Query failed: Unknown column '00C' in 'where clause'..This is the error i am getting

Answer (score 0):

you have used wrong quotes. please try with below query

```
$query1= "SELECT distinct c.airport_ident,c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
         INNER JOIN
         (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type
          FROM corept.std_star_leg
          WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='$col_value'
          GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
          ON c.sequence_num=b.seq AND c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
          WHERE  c.data_supplier='J'  AND c.airport_ident='$col_value'  AND

          NOT EXISTS

         (SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d
          WHERE d.apt=$col_value AND d.name!=d.trans
          AND c.star_ident=d.name and c.fix_ident=d.trans)

          UNION

         SELECT apt,name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d WHERE apt='$col_value' AND name!=trans
         AND

         NOT EXISTS

        (SELECT distinct c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
         INNER JOIN
         (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type FROM corept.std_star_leg
          WHERE data_supplier='J'  AND  airport_ident='$col_value'
          GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
          ON c.sequence_num=b.seq  AND  c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
          WHERE c.data_supplier='J' AND  c.airport_ident=$col_value AND d.name=c.star_ident  AND d.trans=c.fix_ident)";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your query with this:**

```
$query1= 'SELECT distinct c.airport_ident,c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type
      FROM corept.std_star_leg
      WHERE data_supplier="J" AND airport_ident='.$col_value.'
      GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
      ON c.sequence_num=b.seq AND c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
      WHERE  c.data_supplier="J"  AND c.airport_ident='.$col_value.'  AND

      NOT EXISTS

     (SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d
      WHERE d.apt=$col_value AND d.name!=d.trans
      AND c.star_ident=d.name and c.fix_ident=d.trans)

      UNION

     SELECT apt,name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d WHERE apt='.$col_value.' AND name!=trans
     AND

     NOT EXISTS

    (SELECT distinct c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type FROM corept.std_star_leg
      WHERE data_supplier="J"  AND  airport_ident='.$col_value.'
      GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
      ON c.sequence_num=b.seq  AND  c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
      WHERE c.data_supplier="J" AND  c.airport_ident=$col_value AND d.name=c.star_ident  AND d.trans=c.fix_ident)';
```

Comment: Thank you..it worked..but the query is getting replaced as OOC what i need is to be replaced as 'OOC'.How can i do that?

Comment: I am getting error in query..the col_value is a string and it has to be replaced in the query as 'col_value' so that the query works fine

Answer (score 0):

I think the error lies on your query string. try this:

```
$query1= "SELECT distinct c.airport_ident,c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type
      FROM corept.std_star_leg
      WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='".$col_value."'
      GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
      ON c.sequence_num=b.seq AND c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
      WHERE  c.data_supplier='J'  AND c.airport_ident='".$col_value."'  AND

      NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d
  WHERE d.apt=$col_value AND d.name!=d.trans
  AND c.star_ident=d.name and c.fix_ident=d.trans)

  UNION

 SELECT apt,name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_stars d WHERE apt='".$col_value."' AND name!=trans
 AND

 NOT EXISTS

(SELECT distinct c.star_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_star_leg c
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT star_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type FROM corept.std_star_leg
  WHERE data_supplier='J'  AND  airport_ident='".$col_value."'
  GROUP BY star_ident,transition_ident)b
  ON c.sequence_num=b.seq  AND  c.star_ident=b.star_ident AND c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident
  WHERE c.data_supplier='J' AND  c.airport_ident='".$col_value."' AND d.name=c.star_ident  AND d.trans=c.fix_ident)"
```

You can't just include the variable in your query. And test your query at the backend before putting it on php.